# How can I take array input of any size? I tried doing with this code but don't know where the error is. Please Help me Out

Tags: c++, arrays, size, string-length

How can I take array input of any size? I tried doing with this code but don't know where the error is. Please Help me Out

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int arr[10000];
int i;
int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
if(i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
{
  cin>>arr[i];
}
cout << "The size of the array is: " << arrSize;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `if(i=0; i<arrSize; i++)` supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly consider posting the actual errors you are getting. By the way, your code is redundant.

Comment: In this code, the size of the array is 10000. If the goal is to set the size of the array at runtime, the solution is `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `for` instead of `if`. Also, no need to do that sizeof thing. Just put the size of the array there or take the number of elements as an input from the user.